# Range for loop: VS 2008 doesnt support it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to run the following piece of code on VS 2008.

```
int main(){
for(int n: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) // the initializer may be a braced-init-list
        std::cout << n << ' ';

return 0; 
}
```

But the compiler gives me the following warning:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'

It seems to me that VS 2008 doesn't support range for loop. Is that true?
Thx

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with C++11?

Comment: @BatCoder: Considering C++11 refers to the year 2011, and VS2008 to the year 2008, I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The range `for` loop and the initializer list notation that you are using were both introduced in the C++11 standard.

The earliest VC compiler that supports the range `for` loop is VC2013, but that  compiler doesn't implement (or even claim to implement) the C++11 standard fully.
(For example it will not allow you to use the initializer list in the way you have.)

You best upgrade to VC2015.

Comment: Alternatively if you are stuck with VC2008, use BOOST_FOREACH